# Passing url query string value to a view template in angular route

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I am new to AngularJS. I am trying to rewrite my site that use JQuery.

In my existing site I use 
`$(document).on("click",".movieposter",function(){
    window.open("moviedetail.html?id="+this.id);
});` to open a detail page of current page.

I am trying to use AngularJS route to get same function. I did my research, but I cold not figure out how to do it. I am stuck in following code.

```
 .state('moviedetail', {
        url: "/moviedetail?id",
        templateUrl: "views/moviedetail.html",
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
            alert($stateParams.id);  //*** Exists! ***//
        }

    })
```

I got url that has id of a movie that is going to use to get movie detail information. How can I pass that movie id to view template that will display detail view. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does data come from for movie? Usually use that id to get data from API and set scope variable with response

Comment: Hi charietfl, thanks for your answer. Is there anyway to pass query strings from url to templateUrl without using controller? So, I could use moviedetail.html without writing many codes.

Comment: yes... `templateUrl` can be a function

Answer (score 0):

Use state params to pass an object.

```
ui-sref="movielist({movie: movieDetails})"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers Vinay and charlietfl. I learned some new knowledge by doing research based on your answer. Using state params to pass an object is a good idea. And I found out about resolve statement too. Nevertheless, I decided to use localStorage instead of passing an object as parameter. I only use state param to pass id of a movie.

Here is html:

`<a class="moreInfo" ng-click="save({{movie}})" ui-sref="moviedetail({id: {{movie.id}}})"> Find Out More </a>`

Here is save method in movie controller:

```
 $scope.save = function (movie) {
       localStorage.setItem(movie.id, JSON.stringify(movie));
 }
```

Here is how I get data in MovieDetail Controller:

```
var movie = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(id));
```